# TextPad keeps other windows and apps from being in front or on top

Tags: windows-xp, textpad

My copy of Textpad on Windows XP has started acting up where it will not let other applications, programs or windows be in front or go on top of it.

So if I'm using TextPad and I Alt + Tab to Firefox then TextPad's bar goes dim like it knows its not the "top window" but Firefox isn't placed on top of TextPad.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling TextPad but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you have TextPad set to "always on top"? Check in the preferences. (http://forums.textpad.com/viewtopic.php?t=7603&highlight=always+top)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle the stay on top feature.

In the help it says it's an option in the system menu but my Textpad doesn't have any menu called "System".

I finally found it in the following:

> Configure → Preferences → View

It's a checkbox about 14 options down called "Stay on top of other windows".

Comment: Yeah man, that was it. You the man. It was driving me crazy

Comment: This seems to be on by default now in the latest version (7.4.0).

Comment: On by default on my installation too.  If you are the developer that made the decision to keep Textpad on top by default, you need to take a good long look at yourself and think about what you've done, and hang your head in shame.